# How do I exclude a permission group in Laravel 5.3 route middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, permissions, routes

Take the following:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'holidays', 'middleware' => 'permissions', 'permissions' => ['RD - CP - Holidays - R', 'RD - CP - Holidays - RW']],  function () {
        Route::get('', 'Operations\Personnel\HolidayController@home');
```

That R group is the entire company, near enough 400 people, bar about 30, which is not elegant. I want to be able to put a permissions group in there that will deny access to the holidays route.

I'm researching, the best I can find so far is to write a custom middleware, but before I commit to a fairly high labour solution, is there a way to simply tell Laravel to exclude members of a permission group?

Comment: Writing a custom middleware is not a high labor solution it can be done in abt three minutes

Comment: Writing a new middleware would be your best best and it roughly takes less than a minute. `php artisan make:middleware`

Comment: @RajenderJoshi I added two minutes for the permissions logic ;-p

Answer (score 0):

Writing a custom middleware was a lot easier than I thought it would be.